# Angular momentum of rod about different frames

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, angular-momentum

The way we calculate angular momentum of any object, say rod, about it's centre is just L = r × mv or simply Iw.

This is the case when the axis is passing through the centre of the rod while remaining static i.e., not rotating with the object.

Now, suppose we stand at the centre of the rod and then try to calculate the angular momentum. With respect to us, the rod is not rotating at all because we are rotating with it, although the world is rotating w.r.t us. Also, since our velocity is zero and thus dv = 0 or the frame can be considered inertial. Then why is the ambiguity coming in?

Answer (score 0):

A rotating frame is not intertial.  Objects in it will not obey Newton's Laws. For example, in your case if you throw an object radially outward from you it will veer off to one side for no apparent reason (Coriolis Effect).

Comment: So how will we be able to calculate angular momentum from that frame.

Comment: Angular momentum of the rod? That would be zero in a frame spinning with the rod